# How to hide a button on an app with multiple windows? - Objective C OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, window, hide

I have an application which has a button on the first window, once pressed this button should hide and perform an action, to hide the button i'm using this code:

```
[self.myButton setHidden:TRUE];
```

This works fine until I have multiple windows - new instances of this window do not have this button it's hidden by default. However when I create a new window and press the myButton on the first window it doesn't hide the button.

Furthermore if I create a new window and then close that window and press the myButton on the first and now only window it crashes.

It's clear it always seems to target the last window created, how can I make it always target the first window created, or the window the action is actually being sent from?

New windows are simply being created by calling a newDocument from the document controller like so:
    [dc newDocument:self];

Answer (score 0):

Most button actions look like this:

```
- (void)someAction:(NSButton* sender) {}
```

*or*

```
func someAction(sender : NSButton) {}
```

As you can see, a sender is passed with the action. Now this sender is actually the button you pressed. So you can simply hide this particular button by calling `sender.hidden = true;`

The sender is automatically added when you use `Storyboards` or `Xibs` to add the actions.
If you add the action programmatically, add a colon after the selector (ObjC) or string (Swift). The button instance should be passed to you then.

```
... action:@selector(someAction:)...
```

*or*

```
... action:"someAction:" ...
```